# How to filter a Array of objects based on value of other array?

Tags: javascript

```
const Fruits = [
{name:"Apple", color:"red", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Apple", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Banana", color:"yellow", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Banana", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Grape", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"older"},
{name:"Onion", color:"yellow", type:"greenery", condition:"new"},
]

const filter = ["fruit", "green", "new"];
```

How to filter the array ignoring the key, using only the value? I tried to use filter, but only returns me one category

```
let result = Fruits.filter(e => filter.includes(e.type))
```

I would like a result like this:

```
  result = [
     {name:"Apple", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
     {name:"Banana", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
    ]
```

Comment: "green" and "greenary" are not the same. Did you expect that to be in your output?

Comment: Best to give the expected output for what you are asking. We can't tell if your filter elements should appear in _all_ properties or just _some_, or even whether the ordering of elements in your filter array are important (because it should be a set otherwise). There are too many variables, so please let use know _exactly_ what you expect, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an Array of the values for each Object as you iterate, and then use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test that all values match in the filters Array

```js
const Fruits = [
  {name:"Apple", color:"red", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
  {name:"Apple", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
  {name:"Banana", color:"yellow", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
  {name:"Banana", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
  {name:"Grape", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"older"},
  {name:"Onion", color:"yellow", type:"greenery", condition:"new"},
]

const filter = ["fruit", "green", "new"];

const newArray = Fruits.filter((fruit) => {
  return filter.every(x => Object.values(fruit).includes(x));
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Based on the sample result, I think he wants `.every()`, not `.some()`.

Comment: Yeah, I've made this adjustment as soon as the example was provided

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to filter the `Fruits` array by the `color`, `type` and `condition` keys, where if any of those include the values in the `filter` array, then they should be included in the filtered result.

One simple soltion to achieve that would be via the following filter logic using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
// fruit is current array item in Fruits being tested/filtered
filter.includes(fruit.color) && 
filter.includes(fruit.type) && 
filter.includes(fruit.condition)
```

A complete example for this, based on your snippet would be:

```js
const Fruits = [
{name:"Apple", color:"red", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Apple", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Banana", color:"yellow", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Banana", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"new"},
{name:"Grape", color:"green", type:"fruit", condition:"older"},
{name:"Onion", color:"yellow", type:"greenery", condition:"new"},
]

const filter = ["fruit", "green", "new"];

const result = Fruits.filter(fruit => {
  return filter.includes(fruit.color) && filter.includes(fruit.type) && filter.includes(fruit.condition);
})

console.log(result);
```

Hope that helps!